# Is there a way to force a href="#id" to not refresh the page but to just jump to the element ID?

Tags: jquery, html, angular

I made this hacky about page which opens when clicked and closes when clicked again, it is just a div textbox which shows in my main jumbotron.

I have an about on the navbar and I am trying to jump to the about div with it but when I press an a href="#about" from multiple pages in my single page angular 2 app when it is not on the root route, even though the div which holds the #about div which pops up on clicking the nav is viewable from any route, it takes me to root and reloads the page which is not what I want.

Is there a way to force the page not to reload and for it to look in the current page for the div id #about?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: By default a link with `href="#about"` should not refresh your page. So there must be something in your code that triggers a refresh

Comment: the about div is on my root route component template and when I am deep into nested routes and templates and click it it reloads the page.

Comment: try `<a href="http://example.com" (click)="return false;">Link</a>`

Answer (score 1):

https://plnkr.co/edit/kLPQ8NXvSSEwLWU5r0nS?p=preview

Here it is. It's relatively simple. Just have the href and the id of the element you wish to jump to match.

```
<a href="#gohere">Jump</a>

<div style="height: 2000px; width: 100%; background-color:grey"></div>

<div id="gohere">You're here!</div>

<div style="height: 2000px; width: 100%; background-color:grey"></div>
```

Comment: Ya I am doing exactly that but because my #about div is in my home/root component when I am on child routes and I click the navbar it reloads my entire page and takes me back to root route. I need something which deals with that specific situation. Thanks though

Comment: Is the about div still on your DOM?

Comment: The div it loads onto *ngIf="clicked" is visible and loaded onto the same page as my child routes if thats what you mean, though only my [''] root route loads it there.

Comment: If it's not on the dom at when the user clicks the anchor it won't be able to find it. Angular routers provide the ability to dynamically change components loaded on the dom without reloading the entire page. I think you might to look into using nested views instead of hrefs! I'm not at a computer now though so so I can't provide an example. I can update tomorrow if you're curious.

Comment: Sorry I can't provide a more specific solution. It's hard without seeing code or an example.

Comment: Simplest way I can explain it is that my app-root calls my body component which renders a big jumbotron wrapped in a header and my about page is a div with an *ngIf clicked the div will display. The div has an id and my navbar goes to that ID. If I am on my root / then this works perfectly from anywhere on the page. If I am on another page say /profile then it goes to root instead of just jumping to the jumbotron and showing the div